# Is there an expression for a black hole in global deSitter coordinates?

Tags: black-holes, de-sitter-spacetime

The usual deSitter-Schwartzchild black hole is expressed in terms of the static patch, is there a coordinate patch and metric that describes global deSitter with a black hole?